# WP7 Custom applications OTA installation

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, ota

Is it possible to send application in developement on visual studio to WP7 phone after this phone was declare for developement ?

If it's possible how to do that ? need the phone activate some specific configuration to install ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no supported way to wirelessly side-load an application to the phone.